# Explain the differences in setting up a web dev environment on Mac

Tags: ruby, bundler, homebrew, heroku-toolbelt

I'm new to web development and as I research how to install various dev tools on my Mac the following questions have come up,

- Should I install Heroku via the [standalone toolbelt](https://toolbelt.heroku.com/standalone) or via homebrew?
  Isn't the point of homebrew to manage non-Apple packages in a single place.
- Ruby development using the bundler gem again seems like a wise decision, so that gems are no longer installed via gem install  but rather with a project Gemfile. This would suggest that the only gem install required is Bundler. However, then I see developers install a range of tools like this

  `gem install bundler foreman pg rails thin --no-rdoc --no-ri`

  Is this just laziness or is there some reasoning behind this choice that I don't understand?

Comment: Hi, try to be more specific on your questions and you will get more help.

Answer (score 1):

`bundler` and `foreman` I understand being outside of the project.  Bundler for obvious reasons, and foreman because sometimes it doesn't like to run in the constraints of the bundle very well, but to my knowledge there is no reason to install `pg`, `rails`, and `thin` outside the bundle.

In certain bundler configurations, bundler will check for locally installed gems and use them as part of the bundle, while in others, it does not.  Perhaps the reason for installing that suite of gems is to prevent multiple versions of the gem being installed in different projects on the system, essentially acting as a global repository of gems.

In all honesty, I'm brainstorming on this one, but its the only logical explanation I can come up with, hopefully someone can answer this better than myself.